# Reading /proc/kpagecount from python

Tags: python, linux, endianness

I am trying to read the linux /proc/kpagecount from python

kpagecount stores an array of entries, each entry is a 64-bit count of the number of times a physical frame was referenced. I can read 8 bytes (64 bits) normally from python

```
f = open("/proc/kpagecount", "rb")
a = f.read(8)
```

a is a string. I don't know how to interpret the integer value of those 6 bytes though, because it can be big endian, little endian, or any other way of encoding. I can't find information about the format as well. How can I figure that out?

Answer (score 1):

You can find your system's endianess using:
`import sys; print(sys.byteorder)`

Now that you can determine the endianess, read iteratively 8 bytes of the binary file, and store them in an `array`. If it is `little endian`, store them in reverse order (`tbl.size -i -1`), otherwise in regular order. [See endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Finally, merge these 8 bytes so as to reconstruct a whole 64bit number:

- create an `unsigned long long` variable, lets say `X`, and initialise it to `0`.
- read in a for loop, starting from `0`, all the previously stored bytes and:
- add them to the **shifted by 8 bits** `X` variable
- - `X+= (X<<8) + array[i]`